# Why won't meteor 1.0.0 run app but crashes spawn enomem?

Tags: meteor, out-of-memory, spawn, enomem

Made complete clean install of Centos OpenVZ server running 7 minimal 64bit, 2 'slices' of VPS with 2Gb ram, 2 cpus, 2gb swap etc,

Installed virtualmin/webmin that is all, only configuration undertaken in iptables firewall,

No other apps or software installed, only yum update ran,

Then downloaded meteor using curl link,

followed instructions to letter and in /root/ ran meteor create command,

this created myapp then cd myapp into /myapp directory, ran meteor,

repeatedly crashes with this error message,  Why??

Have searched web for answers and no one seems to know, this is a recurrent problem with meteor since 2013 and even before if you research web so why hasn't it been fixed?  And why is it so difficult to get the software to run 'out of the box' its whole premise is its user friendliness and ability to save time, I would love to be able to use it and have signed up to some basic training so really need to get this working!  It should not be this difficult!  Especially when just running the tutorial app...

Thanks for any help and advice you can give,

```
[root@server myapp]# ls
myapp.css  myapp.html  myapp.js
[root@server myapp]# meteor
[[[[[ ~/myapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.

/root/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.ki0ccv++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                                            throw(ex);
                                                  ^
Error: spawn ENOMEM
     at errnoException (child_process.js:1011:11)
     at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:958:11)
     at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:746:9)
     at [object Object]._.extend._spawn (/tools/runners/run-app.js:255:31)
     at [object Object]._.extend.start (/tools/runners/run-app.js:85:22)
     at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:716:16)
     at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:858:28)
     at /tools/runners/run-app.js:396:12
[root@server myapp]#
```

[top image not using any ram or resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPzbT.png)

Answer (score 0):

Stack Enomem is due to interaction between node.js and OpenVZ, I would highly recommend using KVM instead with CENTOS7 upgraded (at cost of only 2 dollars) and this memory problem went away,

For rest of problems with accessing web dev server see advice given to me on meteor forum,

https://forums.meteor.com/t/first-attempt-at-tutorial-app-crashes-on-execution/13920?u=tombranley